# replacing a 40 alphanumeric string in shell

Tags: regex, shell, sed, grep

I'm trying to figure out how to replace a string like this in about 4 dozen files.
The string is the like of "{xyz}:9e665f0954513845ea1779ff762e933dbbea4dfb" where {xyz} (without the braces) is a random docker image name, the 40 character alphanumeric string that comes after the colon is the image tag.

I'm trying to strip out that image tag and replace it with latest as so:

```
my-cool-image:9e665f0954513845ea1779ff762e933dbbea4dfb
```

to become:

```
my-cool-image:latest
```

I can't figure out the right regexp considering that it is a mixed bag of lower case characters [a-z] and numbers [0-9], 40 long.

what is the regex that would help me get these strings replaced using sed?  Is there an alternative way?

My thanks in advance

Comment: `sed -i.bak -E 's/:[a-z0-9]{40}/:latest/' file`

Comment: This one did nothing other than generat 40 *.bak files for some reason

Comment: That changes files inline when there are `40` akphanumerics after a colon.

Comment: @SteveMustafa: A way to do it in awk `awk  'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"} $2 ~ /[[:alnum:]]{40}/ {$2="latest"}1' file`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this with [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) :

```
$ echo 'my-cool-image:9e665f0954513845ea1779ff762e933dbbea4dfb' |
    sed -E 's/:[[:xdigit:]]+/:latest/'
```

```
my-cool-image:latest
```

`[[:xdigit:]]` is a [posix](/questions/tagged/posix) character class to match hexadecimal characters, check [doc](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions/POSIX_Basic_Regular_Expressions)

Comment: Thank you, TIL - but how can I expand this to read lines in 40 files?

Comment: of course,  "-i" if I had my head on my shoulders.   My thanks, once again